# What should I do with stopped, dead, threads? Alive == False

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, delegates

I spawned some threads using ThreadStart and a few of them died for various reasons (the work is complete, or there was an error)

Since I still have a reference to this thread, what should I do do complete the termination of this object?  What can I do to restart it?

Comment: Have you considered using a thread pool instead of manually managing threads?

Comment: I'd like to make sure that only one thread is ever doing a particular task.  What is the correct way to approach this if not ThreadStart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to complete the termination.

You can't restart a thread which has finished - but you could create a *new* thread to do the same task, assuming you know what that task was.

Comment: I rely on the thread name to tell me what it's doing.  Do you see any issue with me appending -dead-randomNumber to the thread name?

Comment: @makerofthings: I tend to avoid using names for that sort of thing. You could use `Thread.ManagedThreadId` as an identifier.

Comment: Thanks! - I'll use a dictionary to refer to the IDs.